# foreach возвращает только 1 результат с запроса

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

Мой запрос:

```
     $query = "select 
              * 
       from 
              news 
       join 
              news_theme_items 
        on 
              news.id = news_theme_items.news_id

      ORDER BY news_theme_items.news_id DESC
       LIMIT 3";

    $thm_items = $this->db->fetchAll($query);
```

После его выполнения я получаю 3 записи из базы данных

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21731
            [is_new] => 1
            [type_id] => 0
[1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21732
            [is_new] => 1
            [type_id] => 1
[2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21733
            [is_new] => 1
            [type_id] => 2
```

После того, как я пытаюсь все это провести через foreach:

```
foreach($thm_items as $item) { var_dump($item); exit; }
```

То я получаю лишь один результат:

```
Array
    (
        [id] => 21731
        [is_new] => 1
        [type_id] => 0
```

Я пробовал давать и $key foreach, но все тот же результат, есть идеи почему это происходит?

Comment: Уберите exit из цикла

Comment: Эммм... Ну так вы же exit делаете. Поэтому и один результат. Уберите его и будет нормально

Comment: Всем спасибо) Вопрос закрыт

Comment: @AK, ответы в ответы.

Answer (score 2):

[Функция exit()](http://www.php.su/exit) заканчивает выполнение скрипта.

Вы после первого прохода по циклу завершаете его.

Уберите exit и будет так, как вам нужно -- полный обход по массиву:

```
foreach($thm_items as $item) { var_dump($item); }
```